# error a usar informacion de un array obtenido de un JSON

Tags: angularjs-2.0

[image: Error al cargar los datos del array]

Agradezco me pueda ayudar con este error; ya traigo el array como se ve en console, pero cuando lo trato de vincular a un `<li>` solo me sale

> Response with status: 200 OK for URL:
>   `http://192.168.0.20/tracker/CodeIgniter-Rutas//index.php/ruta`

actualmente estoy tratando de hacer el llamado a los datos asi:

```
<ul *ngFor="let serial of infoGPS; let i = index">
    <li>{‌{i}} {‌{ serial.serial }}</li>
</ul>
```

y también lo he intentado directo:

```
 <h3><strong class="text-primary">{‌{_PeticionesService.infoGPS.serial}} </strong></h3>
```

Pero no consigo que me muestre los datos del array.

Comment: puedes mostrar el componente?

Answer (score 1):

Te falta llamar al método json, Prueba

```
this._http.get(`url`).map((res) => res.json())
```